# ArcGIS Package information?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I'd like to know how deal with the ArcGIS Package information?
I have ArcGIS 9.3.1 and would like to know how to work with map packages, and layer packages.
Also how do I access it?

Comment: Map packages are available for ArcGIS 10 only, you can find help on layer packages in the ArcGIS Online help, or maybe you want to talk about data package (which requires the Publisher extension). Please add more information on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could begin by reading the [online help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=welcome) prior to installing it to see if it meets your needs.  If it does, install it. using the installation disk.

Answer (score 2):

It is a method for packaging up mxd and ArcExplorer files.

http://www.arcgisblog.com/content/2010/01/arcgis-10-package-mxd-and-all-its-data-map-package

Answer (score 0):

there are several types of packages arcmap can create.

1. right click on a single layer, and choose create layer package. 
   This creates an lpk.
2. right click on a group of layers, and choose create layer package.
   This creates an lpk.
3. right click on a dataframe name, and choose create map package.
   this creates an mpk.

Each has it's usability.
The structure is like this...

[image: layerpackage]

The location that it "unzips" to is...
drive letter:/users/username/my documents/ArcGIS/packages/packagename

The files are simply a zip file with an arcmap extension.
Once you unzip one it cannot be unzipped again (with arcmap doing the unzipping) until the uncompressed folder is deleted from the packages folder.
[That is why you will see an error if you double click on it twice].

In an lpk there will be an lyr file pointing to each layer in the package.
In an mpk there will be an mxd file pointing to all the data in the package as well as the lyr files for each layer.   If you package it from 9.3 it will only make a 9.3 version of the data. if you package from 10.0x or 10.1x it will create a 9.3 version and a 10 version.
There is help for all of this but just creating/clicking/experimenting is really what it takes to get a full understanding of what all happens.